# How to exclude DB connection settings from a SCMP?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, version-control, schema

We have a solution we use to update our database, which includes several "schema comparison" (`.scmp`) files.  These files provide a convenient way to quickly open a tab that compares the schema of the project with the DB's schema.  The trouble is, the DB connection string is embedded in the `.scmp` file, meaning that each developer has to change the file to their specific DB connection settings to use the file.  This means they have to remember to always exclude it from source control to avoid their DB settings getting checked in.

Is there a way to avoid this problem?  Perhaps, say, pulling in the settings from a `connectionStrings.config` file which is not checked into source control, and is specific to that developer's setup?  That's how we deal with getting the connection strings into our `Web.config`, using the `<connectionStrings configSource...` functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I just ended up treating the entire `.scmp` like a `connectionStrings.config` file, and excluding it from source control.  It's mostly per-machine/per-developer stuff in there anyway, so I provide an example SCMP file `comparison.example.scmp` that should be renamed to an SCMP file `comparison.scmp` that is excluded from source control through `.tfignore` (or `.gitignore` if you're using git).

As far as I can tell, though, there is no way to extricate specific database connection string settings from the SCMP files; you just need to include or exclude the whole thing.

Comment: I do the same thing, and also setup a pre-build event to copy the file for you on the first build: IF NOT EXIST $(ProjectDir)\SchemaCompare\YourFile.scmp copy ...